# Other ways to say "if I understood correctly"

Tags: grammaticality

I'm looking a way to say "If I understood correctly" more briefly, I tend to say `If I got this right` but don't know if this sounds good. Maybe `If I get this right` or other way would be better. Any tips?

Context: when someone explains something and I wanna to check if I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of your first idea is good. I think the normal English usage is the present tense ("If I understand...", not "If I understood..."). Also you don't need the word "correctly" (If you understand, then by definition your understanding is correct!)

So in summary: "If I understand, you are saying that..."

Other possible wordings come from the counselling and relationship area:

I think you are saying that..."

"This is what I heard..."

Comment: Nevertheless, people **do** say 'If I understand correctly' - you might _think_ you understand, but have got it wrong!

Comment: Absolutely. I guess my focus was on a grammatical answer to the question, which was how one might shorten the sentence...